# How to style a ButtonGroup so it doesn't change the form's width with the addition more names in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-component

I currently have a component that takes in some data(names), loops through the names and returns a `ButtonGroup` with a checkbox next to each one. The problems is that if I pass in more names, it makes the form component that it's in wider since it keeps rendering the check boxes one after the other one. So I was wondering how I can make that `ButtonGroup` a fixed width so it doesn't change the forms width and renders the check boxes on a new row ones it reaches a width.

[image: ButtonGroup should look something like this.]

```
export default function SharedCheckboxGroup(props) {
    return (
            <ButtonGroup>
                {props.names.map((item) => {
                    return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <label>
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          name={item}
                          value={item}
                        />&nbsp;
                        {item}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </label>&nbsp;
                      <br />
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                })}
              </ButtonGroup>
            );
```

Comment: are you working with a ui library?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm using React Bootstrap

Comment: try out to remove `<React.Fragment>` and `<br>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim No that doesn't do anything. Wouldn't I have to do styling on the ButtonGroup to get what I want? Maybe using flexbox or grid? I am new to React and CSS so I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: Try out `<ButtonGroup style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'nowrap'}}>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Changed 'nowrap' to 'wrap' and it go what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following inline style :

```
<ButtonGroup style={{display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
```